# How can I get the List (Search) to tell me whether or not each it is in the other List (main)?

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I am trying to compare the List items in two text files the files read

```
Black 10
Brown 22
Orange 29
Red 7
Silver 15
Tan 17
White 0
Yellow 20
Aqua 15
Orange 12
Blue 3
Silver 30
```

and the search file reads

```
Brown 22
Silver 30
White 10
Blue 3
Blue 13
Yellow 20
Orange 22
Orange 90
```

I would like it to print out something such as:

```
 Brown 22 found in file
 Orange 29 no found in file etc..
```

So far i have this where it is just printing the 2 out and telling you what it is, I just cannot seem to figure a way out to compare the two and tell me if the main item was found or not based on the search items

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {  
   String token1 = "";
   String token2 = "";
   Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new FileReader("Lab2InputFile1.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s");
   Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner (new FileReader("Lab2InputFile2.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s");;
   List <String> temp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   List <String> temp2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
       token1 = inFile1.next();
       temp1.add(token1);
    }
    System.out.println("Main Items are" );
    inFile1.close();
    String [] MainItems = temp1.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (String s: MainItems) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    while (inFile2.hasNext()) {
        token2 = inFile2.next();
        temp2.add(token2);
    }
    System.out.println ("Search Items are");
    inFile2.close();
    String [] SearchItems = temp2.toArray(new String [0]);
    for (String t : SearchItems) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to change the Lists to an array.  Iterate over `temp1` and see if that `temp1` element exists somewhere in `temp2`.  See the [List.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method.

Comment: Are you storing `Black 10` as one element in the list?

Comment: Yes I am i am just using it as a single string

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String item : list1) {
        if (list2.contains(item)) {
            System.out.println(item + " found in file");
        } else {
            System.out.println(item + " not found in file");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `seach array` and check if `source array` contains or not.

The `contains` method is use in that case.

Hope it will help you

```
List<String> source = Arrays.asList("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3");
List<String> search = Arrays.asList("Item 1", "Item 4");
search.stream().forEach(s -> {
    if (source.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println(s + " found in file");
    } else {
        System.out.println(s + " not found in file");
    }
});
```

The result

- Item 1 found in file
- Item 4 not found in file